# How display h:outputText value from bundle file depending of value from data base?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I work with jsf 2.2 and primefaces 7

I don't know how to display a value of genre column with my property file (bundle) in my dataTable UIcomponent :

```
 <p:dataTable id="datalist" id="datalist" value="#{usersBean.items}" var="item"  ... >
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.genre}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.sexe}"/>
        </p:column>
        ...
 </p:dataTable>
```

currently my display is **F** or **M** of my column "genre".

How can I display my genre "outputtext value" from my bundle file according to the value of my column "sexe" from DataBase.

I want to display (english or french) if :

value: F ---> Woman    /    value: M ---> Man

or in french

value: F ---> Femme    /    value: M ---> Homme

my bundle (english) file is :

```
UserGenreF=Woman
UserGenreM=Man
```

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try the following EL: `<h:outputText value="#{msg['UserGenre'.concat(item.sexe)]}"/>` where `msg` is your message bundle EL

Comment: I posted it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EL to be clever and map it for you:

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{msg['UserGenre'.concat(item.sexe)]}"/>
```

where `msg` is your message bundle EL.